# Cannot find package Libvala

Tags: linux, ubuntu, configuration, vala

I'm trying to configure the latest version of monodevelop but I'm stuck. I have the latest version of libvala and versions before that. Could someone please explain this to me.

```
checking for LIBVALA... no
configure: error: Package requirements (libvala-0.12 >= 0.12) were not met:

No package 'libvala-0.12' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables LIBVALA_CFLAGS
and LIBVALA_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

How can I set LIBVALA_LIB? Is LIBVALA a env variable? In the configure.in for the Valabindings it looks like this:

```
PKG_CHECK_MODULES(LIBVALA, libvala-0.12 >= $LIBVALA_REQUIRED_VERSION)
AC_SUBST(LIBVALA_LIBS)
```

What is that? How can I solve this?

Under /usr/lib/pkgconfig I have Libvala-0.12.pc if that can help. And if I run dpkg -i libvala-0.12-0 I get that it's installed and works fine.

Comment: @chikuba: Please accept at least one of the answers to your previous questions.

Comment: there we go :) could you please help me know. would really appreciate it

Answer (score 3):

Do you have `libvala-0.12-dev` installed? What version of Ubuntu do you have?

Comment: I solved it. Had to go in to the configure.in in /extras/Valabindings and change the LIBVALA_REQUIRED_VERSION from 0.12 to 0.12.0.

Answer (score 0):

The version of libvala required is >= libvala-0.12-dev.  Both 0.14 and 0.16 packages are available for Debian Wheezy:

libvala-0.14-dev
libvala-0.16-dev

After installing the package you wish, edit: /extras/Valabinding/configure.in. There is one instance of libvala-0.12. Replace it with the version you want to use (e.g. libvala-0.14).

After making this change, ./configure worked fine.